# Slow screen scrolling in pygame

Tags: scroll, reload, slowdown

I have created a scrolling game using python pygame. Even with just the screen scrolling nothing else running the screen slows down over time. I have set the FPS to 10 and this improves the scrolling speed problem but not eliminate. The screen will come to almost a complete stop. To eliminate the problem I would like to create a controlling program that would run before each level and restart the game from scratch reloading everything. Is this possible?

Slowed dow the FBS to 10 and it helps but does not eliminate the problem and has other issues. I also reduced the size of the big screen but this did not help. I can set a level to run a fixed time then if I can reload everything, problem solved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.